# Remove every n lines for removing datablock using sed or awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a big file made up of 316125000 lines. This file is made up of 112500 data blocks, and each data block has 2810 lines.

I need to reduce the size of the file, so I want to leave the 1st, 10th, 20th, ... 112490th, and 112450th data blocks, and remove all other data blocks. This will gonna give me 11250 data blocks as a result.

This means the same thing that I want to remove every 2811 ~ 28100 lines, and leaving every 1~2810, and 28101~30910 .... lines.

I was thinking of awk, sed or grep, but which one is faster, and how can I acheive this? I know how to remove every 2nd or 3rd line, with awk and NR, but I don't know how to remove big chunk of lines repetitively.

Thanks

Best,

Comment: Note that “1st, 10th, 20th…” isn't every 10th in the beginning of the sequence: 10-1 = 9, 20-10 = 10. Every 10th would be either 10th, 20th, 30th… (without the 1st), or 1st, 11th, 21st… (or equivalently, blocks 0, 10, 20… when numbering from 0). In my answer I'm assuming that you actually meant the latter to avoid making the first block a special case.

Comment: Yes, it seems I did a mistake in here. I was also trying to get every 10th, and the first one become the special, which you already pointed out. That awk code works great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something along these lines might work:

```
awk 'int((NR - 1) / 2810) % 10 == 0' <infile >outfile
```

That is, `int((NR - 1) / 2810)` gives the (zero-based) number of the block of 2810 lines for the current line (`NR`), and if the remainder of that block number divided by ten is 0 (`% 10 == 0`) prints the line. This should result in every 10th block being printed, including the first (block number 0).

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't guess which is fastest, but I can provide a GNU sed recipe for your benchmarking:

```
sed -e '2811~28100,+25289d' <input >output
```

This says: starting at line 2811 and every 28100 lines thereafter, delete it and the next 25289 lines.

Equivalently, we can use `sed -n` and print lines 1-2810 every 28100 lines:

```
sed -ne '1~28100,+2809p' <input >output
```